# Prohibition of Animal Fights in Islam

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, animals, sahaba

Most of the times, I came across the festivals held for animals/birds fighting. These festivals are also held in Muslims countries across the world, so I wonder if **Islam specifically allows or forbids animal/birds fighting**.

These fights include *dog fighting*, *Rooster fighting*, *Partridge fighting* and many more. Most of the times, these fights include the bidding, while animals are hurt severely. How much strictly Islam forbids it? Any story related to **Sahabas** or **Prophet SAWW** would be appreciated (with reference of hadith or Ayah).

Are there any specific rules for halal or haram animals fighting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Animal fighting is forbidden in Islam. There is a hadith on it in Sunan Abu Dawud and Jamee at-Tirmizhi:

> نهى رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم عن التحريش بين البهائم
>
> The Messenger of Allah ﷺ prohibited instigating fights between beasts.

It is also rationally evil because it is cruelty to animals causing suffering and possibly even death without any proper interest served.

Comment: thank you sir for your knowledge with reference.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the instructions during halal slaughter are concerned with the animal not experiencing too much pain , or panicking as a result of seeing another animal being slaughtered , if Islam worries too much about animals that are about to die anyway , I believe it also worries about animals suffering needlessly.
Also don't forget the two hadiths , which I believe every Muslim School boy remembers , about the woman who went to hell for starving a cat and the prostitute that , in a moment of affection , struggled to bring water to a dog dying from thirst and Allah forgave her for it .
I think you can deduce Islam's view on this matter from these examples .

Comment: yes that is a famous story, please try adding reference for future posts. it increases the authencity. regards